# Select URL from an attribute using XPath

Tags: html, xpath

I would like to retrieve the file url from a HTML meta-tag, given in the `content` attribute.

Here is the example HTML code:

```
 <meta content="https://www.domain.com/player/player-viral.swf?config=
https://www.domain.com/configxml?id=133291&logo.
link=http://www.domain.org/Amin+Rostami/-/Havam+Toei&
image=https://www.domain.com/img/3lv68bc5w-1396897306.jpeg&provider=audio&
file=http://s10.domain.me/music/A/[one]/test-msusic.mp3" property="og:video"/>
```

I would like to get the file url, in this case `http://s10.domain.me/music/A/[one]/test-msusic.mp3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring-after()` to extract the link after the `file=` from the `content` attribute of a `meta` tag:

```
substring-after(//meta/@content, "file=")
```

Demo (using `xmllint`):

```
$ cat input.xml
<meta content="https://www.domain.com/player/player-viral.swf?config=
https://www.domain.com/configxml?id=133291&amp;logo.
link=http://www.domain.org/Amin+Rostami/-/Havam+Toei&amp;
image=https://www.domain.com/img/3lv68bc5w-1396897306.jpeg&amp;provider=audio&amp;
file=http://s10.domain.me/music/A/[one]/test-msusic.mp3" property="og:video"/>

$ $ xmllint input.xml --xpath 'substring-after(//meta/@content, "file=")'
http://s10.domain.me/music/A/[one]/test-msusic.mp3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , i am using Drupal Feeds XPath Parser. i can't do that , here my sample url http://www.wikiseda.com/Ali+Lohrasbi/-/Be+Cheshmam+Khire+Sho can you take a look. i added substring-after(//meta/@content, "file=") but its not work.